# Excel - photo in cell with corresponding photo from file

Tags: microsoft-excel, photos

I have a column with .jpg file names listed. I want to have the actual photo appear. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Say column A contains the filespec of the **.jpg** files like:

C:\TestFolder\sample.jpg

Then this little macro will place the actual pictures in column B:

```
Sub PicturePlacer()
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Range, rB As Range
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        Set rB = r.Offset(0, 1)
        s = r.Value
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes
            .AddPicture s, False, True, rB.Left, rB.Top, rB.Width, rB.Height
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```